# Guided waves: showing geometrically that $v_p v_g = c^2$

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, dispersion, waveguide, phase-velocity

In griffith's introduction to electrodynamics p.430 there's a Figure 9.25 of the wavefronts. I'm wondering if we can show geometrically $v_p v_g = c^2$ using this kind of figure. I think so, but I can't figure out how exactly. I also think it can help me to understand the different velocity.

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's sought-for formula (1) for a [waveguide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide) parallel to the $z$-axis is an immediate analytic consequence of the [dispersion relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) for an EM wave in vacuum:
   $$\omega(k_z) ~=~ c\sqrt{k^2_x+ k^2_y+k^2_z}~=~c\sqrt{{\rm const.}+k^2_z},\tag{A}$$
   where the $x$ and $y$ modes are fixed. Then
   $$ v_pv_g~=~\frac{\omega}{k_z} \frac{d\omega}{dk_z}~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~\ldots~=~c^2.\tag{B}$$
2. Returning to OP's question: Geometrically Griffith argues that if $\theta$ denotes the angle between the EM wave and the waveguide, then the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) $v_g=c\cos\theta$ is simply the projection, while the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) $v_p=c/\cos\theta$ is given by velocity of the [wavefronts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront) along the wall of the waveguide, cf. Fig. 9.25.